# p-table set defalt page

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

My english is very poor

I am using p-table with paginator, but i need change the pagination, . html code

```
     <p-table #dt [columns]="cols" [value]="values"
          [paginator]="true"
          [rows]="10"
          (onFilter)="filtrado($event)" 
          [scrollable]="true"  
          [style]="{'width':'100%'}"

          >
......
    </p-table>
```

and ts

```
  @ViewChild('dt') dt: Table;
```

But i don`t know how to made it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `first` input property. It must depend on your `pageSize * n` where n is your desired page number.

```
  <p-table #dt [columns]="cols" [value]="values"
      [paginator]="true"
      [first]="first"
      [rows]="10"
      (onFilter)="filtrado($event)" 
      [scrollable]="true"  
      [style]="{'width':'100%'}"

      >
```

......

`this.first = this.pageSize * 2;` shows page 2. And so on.

Comment: Hi Kraken. I try this way,  if i put **first=4;**  i am the first page, where is **this.pageSize**, thanks for your help.

Comment: Page size may be a number just like 10 ir 100 this us a items count in your page